# dlv-dap fails to install for Go in VS Code on Windows for because of a malformed path

Tags: windows, go, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am trying to get up VSCode in a virtual machine running Windows Server 2019 to allow debugging Windows-specific Go programs but when I try to compile and VSCode asks to install the tools it fails to install `dlv-dap` although installs the other tools fine. *(I am new to VSCode and have not really used Windows in over 10 years, but have programmed for decades and in Go on macOS for several years now.)*

The problem as you can see from the output is that `bin` has been duplicated in the `go.exe` path, e.g.:

```
C:\\Users\\Administrator\\go\\bin\\bin\\go.exe
```

I have reinstalled Go and reinstalled VSCode, I have moved around GOPATH and GOROOT, I have tried doing without GOPATH and GOROOT, I have added GOPATH and GOROOT to the `settings.json` file, and always the same problem.

This leads me to think this is a bug, but I wanted to make sure that it wasn't me doing something stupid before I reported it on GitHub, as they suggest in their directions for bug submission.

For this output I have these setting in my User environment:

- My `GOROOT` is `C:\Users\Administrator\go\bin`
- My `GOPATH` is `C:\Users\Administrator\go`

I also installed `dlv-dap` via command line outside of VSCode, but VSCode did not recognize that I had done so.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Also, where would I look for the source code that runs this install to see if I can determine if there is an error and if an error submit a pull request fixing it?

Thanks in advance for any help you might provide.

```
Tools environment: GOPATH=C:\Users\Administrator\go
Installing 8 tools at C:\Users\Administrator\go\bin in module mode.
  gopkgs
  gotests
  gomodifytags
  impl
  goplay
  dlv
  dlv-dap
  staticcheck

Installing github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/v2/cmd/gopkgs@latest (C:\Users\Administrator\go\bin\gopkgs.exe) SUCCEEDED
Installing github.com/cweill/gotests/gotests@latest (C:\Users\Administrator\go\bin\gotests.exe) SUCCEEDED
Installing github.com/fatih/gomodifytags@latest (C:\Users\Administrator\go\bin\gomodifytags.exe) SUCCEEDED
Installing github.com/josharian/impl@latest (C:\Users\Administrator\go\bin\impl.exe) SUCCEEDED
Installing github.com/haya14busa/goplay/cmd/goplay@latest (C:\Users\Administrator\go\bin\goplay.exe) SUCCEEDED
Installing github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest (C:\Users\Administrator\go\bin\dlv.exe) SUCCEEDED
Installing github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@2f13672765fe FAILED
{
 "errno": -4058,
 "code": "ENOENT",
 "syscall": "spawn C:\\Users\\Administrator\\go\\bin\\bin\\go.exe",
 "path": "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\go\\bin\\bin\\go.exe",
 "spawnargs": [
  "get",
  "-x",
  "-d",
  "github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@2f13672765fe"
 ],
 "cmd": "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\go\\bin\\bin\\go.exe get -x -d github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@2f13672765fe",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": ""
}
Installing honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck@latest (C:\Users\Administrator\go\bin\staticcheck.exe) SUCCEEDED

1 tools failed to install.

dlv-dap: failed to install dlv-dap(github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@2f13672765fe): Error: spawn C:\Users\Administrator\go\bin\bin\go.exe ENOENT 
'C:\Users\Administrator\go\bin\go.exe env': warning: GOPATH set to GOROOT (C:\Users\Administrator\go) has no effect
```

Answer (score 1):

And after all that, I removed `go.goroot` and `go.delveConfig` from `settings.json`, and it installed fine and just started working. *(I had added those earlier while trying to debug the problem.)*

This is what I removed from `settings.json`:

```
"go.goroot": "C:\Users\Administrator\go\bin",
"go.delveConfig": {
    "debugAdapter": "legacy",
}
```

I don't know if that "fixed" it, or if something else I did fixed it and that was just leftover cruft, but either way it is working now and *hopefully* this helps someone else that runs into the same issue.